# VB.net Form1 does not open up in design view

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.Net.  I was goofing around and lost the design view of Form1.  Form1 opens up as Form1.Designer.vb.  I want Form1.vb[Design] so I can change the form.  I know it is some small setting.  Thx in advance for your help!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you've turned on Show All Files setting and you're double clicking the designer class file. You can turn off at the top of Solution Explorer or in the Project menu.